SSH Server Connections
I have a quick question that I was hoping someone who knows a lot more about these things than I do could answer. I connect to a lot of computers remotely over SSH for moving files around. I've noticed that the connections seem to be more reliable and quicker if I mount the remote drive using SSHFS vs. using the "connect to server" in Nautilus or Nemo. Is there a different process underlying those two ways of connecting remotely to a server? It's not a big issue or anything, I was just curious and I can't seem to find what Nautilus is using for the "connect to server" feature.
